# OctoberCMS: How to change the view of uploaded files for "attachMany" relation type?

Tags: php, file-upload, octobercms, october-partial

The default view of the `attachMany` relations, tries to show the preview of the file even for non-image files. For example in the following snapshot, october tries to show preview of the `pdf` files:

[image]

As you can see, the preview fails for pdf files. I need to fix this behavior. How can I override the HTML shown for the uploaded files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the fields.yaml config for the form?
I guess it includes

```
type: fileupload
mode: image
```

Mode `image` is what tells october to create thumbnails

Comment: You really should clarify your question!

Comment: Thank you. Changing mode to `file` fixed the problem :)